# MYSQL - order from table by X starting with id Y

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I my mysql db I have a table with 3 parameters ( name, views, id ). I need to get row ordered by views. I'm getting something like this.

query:

```
select 
from table 
order by views
```

Result:

```
   id    |  name   |  views
   ------------------------
   7     |  xxxx   |  9000
   2     |  yyyy   |  8000
   1     |  aaaa   |  7000
   4     |  bbbb   |  6000
   8     |  dddd   |  5000
   6     |  cccc   |  4000
   5     |  oooo   |  3000
   3     |  tttt   |  2000
```

What I need to do, is to get rows ordered by views but starting with specyfic ID. Is it possible. All input that i have is ID. Let sat that ID is 6, this should be output:

```
   id    |  name   |  views
   ------------------------       
   6     |  cccc   |  4000
   5     |  oooo   |  3000
   3     |  tttt   |  2000
```

I can't use LIMIT as I don't really know what is possition at the moment. I just need to get rows which are left starting with ID.

---

What I'm trying to do is to get infinite scroll, I requesting next elements base on last element that was displayed. Only tricky part is that I'm ordering by views parameter.

Comment: I don't see how if you select by id=6, you would also retrieve id=5, id=3. Can you explain why the output should include those rows when id=6 ?

Comment: @Romain, think you misread the question - the table is `table`, the `order` statement is indeed an order statement.

Comment: @SetSailMedia Oh right. No indentation = bad indentation. Fixed my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table
where (views = 4000 and id>6) or (views < 4000) 
order by views desc, id asc;
```

The tricky part is that you have to know (select) the views of the element with ID 6; also you need to use the ID as secondary sort criteria in order to get consistent results.

Actually this is a common case of a since,until type of paging

Comment: One more question, what if I dont know the views count ?

Comment: @KrzysztofAba since you know the ID, you can perform a query to select them. Actually it can be a subquery, so you still can get the results with single query.

Comment: You wrote id asc, I don't think this is correct. What im trying to do is to cut query **bold**`select from table order by views` into parts based on ID. But ordering by id dont make sense as the last one can be id 8 with views number 1

Comment: @KrzysztofAba the id is only for sorting in consistent way the results with the same views count

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE views <= (SELECT views FROM table WHERE id = 6) 
ORDER BY views
```

Comment: But what if there are multiple results with 4000 views?

Comment: @Darhazer: all records with 4000 views will be included in result.

Comment: That will not work I'm getting loop... I'm having a lot of rows with same views count. And I'm limiting each query to 40 elements